# Using jq convert named keys to key value pairs

Tags: arrays, json, nested, jq

I have json like this:

```
{"searchResult":[{"mac":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"time":"2021_04_11 23:45:01"},{"field_1":"87"}]}
{"searchResult":[{"mac":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"time":"2021_04_11 01:10:29"},{"field_2":"Some text"},{"field_3":"8"}]}
{"searchResult":[{"mac":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"time":"2021_04_11 03:49:14"},{"field_1":"92"},{"field_3":"25"}]}
```

Some fields are always present. Others are optional, there are 1000s of possible fields, and new ones can be added at any point. To import into the db (BigQuery), I would like them formatted like:

```
{"searchResult":[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 23:45:01"},{"key":"field_1","value":"87"}]}
{"searchResult":[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 01:10:29"},{"key":"field_2","value":"Some text"},{"key":"field_3","value":"8"}]}
{"searchResult":[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"},{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 03:49:14"},{"key":"field_1","value":"92"},{"key":"field_3","value":"25"}]}
```

So far I have:

```
jq -c '.searchResult[] |= to_entries'
```

Which gives:

```
{"searchResult":[[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"}],[{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 23:45:01"}],[{"key":"field_1","value":"87"}]]}
{"searchResult":[[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"}],[{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 01:10:29"}],[{"key":"field_2","value":"Some text"}],[{"key":"field_3","value":"8"}]]}
{"searchResult":[[{"key":"mac","value":"xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"}],[{"key":"time","value":"2021_04_11 03:49:14"}],[{"key":"field_1","value":"92"}],[{"key":"field_3","value":"25"}]]}
```

We can't have the unnecessary arrays around each key/value object, we can't import nested arrays in BigQuery, and here they are redundant.

I can fix this with sed, but for my own understanding, I would like this all in done in jq.

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Answering my own question. Have found 'flatten', and this does the job:

`jq -c '.searchResult[] |= to_entries' | jq -c '.searchResult |= flatten'` 

Is there a way of doing this within a single command?

Answer (score 0):

The direct, efficient, and robust approach:

```
.searchResult |= map(to_entries[])
```